# Accessing array of objects (or array of arrays) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

In my JavaScript I have an array of data stored in two ways

- as an array of arrays `data1[i++] = [id, url, val]`

and

- as array of objects `data2[i++] = {id:id, url:url, val:val}`

when I will output both arrays to the console I see all data which are correct.

Next I want to access them. For a first set of data I'm doing that:

```
  var total = data1.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < total; j++) {
        console.log(data1[j]);
      }
```

and then for second set of that

```
  var total = data2.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < total; j++) {
        console.log(data2[j].id + data2[j].gradient + data2[j].url);

      }
```

but if I want to use them (data from an object)

```
jQuery( "#' + data2[j].id + ' .banner-bg" ).css( "background-image",  data2[j].url );
```

it throws an error

*Error: Syntax err or, unrecognized expression: # + data[j].id + .banner-bg*

Where I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just escaping your quotes wrong. Do this:

```
jQuery( '#' + data2[j].id + ' .banner-bg' ).css( "background-image",  data2[j].url );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for jQuery wrong. Try this:

```
var arg = '#' + data2[j].id + '.banner-bg';
jQuery(arg).css( "background-image",  data2[j].url );
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
jQuery( "#' + data2[j].id + ' .banner-bg" ).css( "background-image",  data2[j].url );
```

Should be this:

```
jQuery( "#" + data2[j].id + " .banner-bg" ).css( "background-image",  data2[j].url );
```

In the first the whole string including the reference to the array object ( `data2[j].id` ) is being parsed by jQuery.

Read more about JS operators [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).